# How to return value from C program to Python script

Tags: python, c, python-3.x

When I try to return value from c code to python code i got error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python.py", line 54, in <module>
    print("\n\n\n\RESULT: ", str(result, "utf-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xba in position 245: invalid start byte
```

in c function i try to return json string which got hex data  - which I could parse in python and than make another calculation.

Example of returned string is "{"data":"0x123132"}"

In python i use

```
import ctypes

my_functions = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("./my_functions.so")


my_functions.getJson.argtypes = (ctypes.c_char_p,)

my_functions.EthereumProcessor.restype = ctypes.c_char_p

result=my_functions.getJson()

print("\n\n\n\RESULT: ", str(result, "utf-8"))
```

Comment: Is it `latin1`?

Comment: What do you mean? It's default character on English keyboard

Comment: This is happening because whatever `byte` string you are dealing with is not a valid `utf-8` string. You could try `str(result, "latin1")`?